# How to remove space between svg based pie chars slices?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, pie-chart

I have this code based on [Lea Verou svg based pie chart](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/#svg-solution) using Angular

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('main', function() {
    // taken from api
    var counters = {
        "missingAuthorSignature": 60,
        "missingWitnessSignature": 70,
        "pendingWitnessSignoff": 8,
        "entitiesTotalCreated": 83,
        "entitiesArchived": 0,
        "entitiesCompleted": 12,
        "entitiesIncomplete": 71,
        "entitiesWitnessed": 38
    };
    this.activity = {
        color: '#1F187A',
        data: [{
            color: '#3D38A4',
            value: counters.entitiesArchived
        }, {
            color: '#645EDB',
            value: counters.entitiesCompleted
        }, {
            color: '#8781FF',
            value: counters.entitiesIncomplete
        }, {
            color: '#828591',
            value: counters.entitiesWitnessed
        }]
    };
    // this part is taken from piechart component
    this.parts = this.activity.data.slice();
    this.all = {
        value: this.parts.reduce((count, part) => {
            return count + part.value;
        }, 0),
        color: this.activity.color
    };
    this.parts.forEach((part) => {
        part.value = part.value * 360 / this.all.value;
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < this.parts.length; ++i) {
        this.parts[i].offset = Math.round(this.parts.slice(0, i).reduce((count, part) => {
            return count + part.value;
        }, 0));
    }
});
```

```css
svg {
    width: 140px; height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
circle {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 116;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
#center {
    r: 25;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main as vm">
<svg viewBox="0 0 116 116">
  <circle id="circle-{{$index}}" r="58" cx="58" cy="58" ng-repeat="part in vm.parts"
          ng-style="{transform: 'rotate({{part.offset}}deg)'}" stroke="{{part.color}}"
          ng-attr-stroke-dasharray="{{part.value}} 360" />
  <circle id="center" cx="58" cy="58" ng-style="{fill: vm.all.color}" />
  <g transform="translate(58,58) rotate(90) translate(0, -45)">
   <text y="50" font-family="Arial" fill="white">
       <tspan x="0" text-anchor="middle">{{vm.all.value}}</tspan>
   </text>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

As you can see when you run the snippet there are gaps between slices, Is it possible to remove them?

Comment: It looks like the semi-circles are misaligned by a pixel or two.  Or the SVGs are not created properly?

Comment: This isn't really a solution, but I think I can tell you what the problem is: `stroke-dasharray` is not 100% accurate. The method used in your example relies on that property which specifies the gap widths between dashes in a stroke. You can see why this is a problem by reducing your list to just one activity. You'll see that the `stroke-dasharray` will have a value of` `360 360`. That should give you a 360 degree dash before the first gap, but chrome doesn't play nice with that value. It still tries to add a gap for the "dashes". That's the root of the issue. Degree values are imprecise here.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by adding 3 to `value` and subtracting 3 in each step when calculating offset:

```
            this.parts.forEach((part) => {
                part.value = part.value * 360 / this.all.value + 3;
            });
            for (var i=0; i<this.parts.length; ++i) {
                this.parts[i].offset = Math.floor(this.parts.slice(0, i).reduce((count, part) => {
                    return count + part.value - 3;
                }, 0));
            }
```